# wpf WindowsFormsHost is not visible when AllowsTransparency="True"

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

somebody addressed this issue here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6f9dd3b5-af92-4076-9b4e-1a770dd52f70/

but that was in 2006. i am currently using .net framework 3.5. Is there any better solution for that now. Does anybody know if microsoft has a straight forward solution for this issue in 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this won't work. Quote from [this](http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/113392/) link

> This is a limitation of using
> WS_EX_LAYERED and
> UpdateLayeredWindow(). This form of
> layered windows does not support child
> windows. This is a Win32 limitation,
> not a WPF limitation. Child windows
> could be used with constant opacity
> (WS_EX_LAYERED and
> SetLayeredWindowAttributes) but WPF
> does not support that mode, as it is
> more restrictive (constant versus
> per-pixel opacity).

The best solution I've been able to find was from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/changov/webbrowser-control-on-transparent-wpf-window) link.

I added a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to the AllowsTransparency Window when I was trying it out, you can download my modified version of it from [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/54p85b45c45wq61/WebBrowserOnTransparentWindow.zip/file).